# ORB feature descriptor

Tags: opencv, vision

I need to program my bot so that it is able to find an object that is it asked to pickup and bring it to the commanded position. I have tried simple img processing techniques like filtering, contour finding. that doesn't seems to work well. I want to use ORB feature extractor. here are a sample images. object of interest is the ball. In short how do I train my bot to pickup balls or other objects any sample program will be helpful. how to use ORB. provide an example if possible. thanx in advance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/spobV.jpg
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNH1T.jpg

Comment: ORB might not be your best choice for this task. The objects you've provided don't contain much surface texture, which ORB (and a lot of other feature detectors) needs to be able to differentiate objects.

Comment: what will be the best or better choice for detecting objects like this. I am able to process the image into more of this form[look at here http://answers.opencv.org/question/6090/locate-the-circle-in-the-image/] but the final output of the process changes with ball color(I updated the hue values for red color) illumination and environment for example [http://www.pasteall.org/pic/43818 ]. is there a unified pipeline to detect the ball and other simple objects without much texture in it??

Answer (score 1):

You can try the learning based algorithms like Haar-classifier to detect any object. Thanks to OpenCV all the training process is very streamlined. All you have to do is to is to train your classifier with some true-image(image of the object) and false images(any possible image not having the object.).

Below are some links for your refrence.

1. Haar trainer for Ball-Pen detection: http://opencvuser.blogspot.com/2011/08/creating-haar-cascade-classifier-aka.html
2. Haar Trainer for Banana Detection :) :http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html